# getting sqlalchemy view reflection to work in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Flask-SQLAlchemy's support of SQLAlchemy's reflection doesn't seem to be working quite right for me. I have a view `my_view` that I want to reflect on via `autoload`.

But I want `my_view` to be a rich object and have various functions so I want `my_view` to subclass `db.Model`. I want it to pretty much work like any other db model that is not a view.

I do it like this:

```
class MyView(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'my_view',
    __table_args__ = (
        db.UniqueConstraint('id', 'start_date'),
        {
            'autoload': True,
            'autoload_with': db.engine
        }
    )

    ...my column defs...

    ...extra functionality...
```

But during app bootstrap time I get an error:

```
<snip>
File "env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py", line 2325, in get_columns
info_cache=kw.get('info_cache'))
File "<string>", line 2, in get_table_oid
File "env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 54, in cache
ret = fn(self, con, *args, **kw)
File "env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py", line 2223, in get_table_oid
    raise exc.NoSuchTableError(table_name)
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError: ('my_view',)
```

However, if I use `db.Table` instead of `db.Model` it works:

```
MyView = db.Table(
    'my_view',
    db.metadata,
    ...my column defs...
    autoload=True,
    autoload_with=db.engine
)
```

I really want to have an object and use `db.Model` though, so I can implement `__eq__()` and `__json__()` and be able to do things like:

```
my_view_rows = session.query(MyView)\
                      .order_by(MyView.column_a)\
                      .all()
```

Anyone know why the `db.Model` version of my code is not working? What do I need to do to get it working?

Answer (score 4):

Using __table__ instead of __tablename__ and __table_args__ works.

```
class MyView(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Table(
        'my_view', db.metadata,
        db.Column('other_table_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('other_table.id'), primary_key=True),
        ...other column defs...
        autoload=True,
        autoload_with=db.engine
    )

    other_table = db.relationship('OtherTable')
```

Comment: I can't get this config to work with Flask blueprints, if you have any input on that I posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826150/sqlalchemy-how-to-reflect-a-view-when-using-flask-blueprints